# HTML inside SVG foreignobject not visible

Tags: scala.js, scalajs-react

I am struggling with an SVG, where I embed HTML via `foreignobject`. Here's a minimal component:

```
val SvgDemoComponent = ReactComponentB[Unit]("Demo")
.render { _ =>
  <.svg.svg(
    <.svg.foreignobject(
      <.div("Hello From SVG")
    )
  )
}
.build
```

The problem is that the "Hello" text is not visible. However, I can make a minor whitespace edit in Chrome or FF and then it becomes visible:

[image]

**Update:** The problem is reproducible with plain React, i.e. it is not caused by the scalajs-react abstraction. I have just posted it as [a new SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39504988/react-svg-html-inside-foreignobject-not-rendered).

Comment: To illustrate that it's working without scalajs-react: https://jsfiddle.net/8v8taqtz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caused by a spelling mistake in scalajs-react: `foreignObject` requires a capital **O**.

[PR](https://github.com/japgolly/scalajs-react/pull/305) submitted.

Comment: PR got merged and the fix is available as of scalajs-react v0.11.2